# Stuck with fetching name through Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public
class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private
    TextView showprofile;
    private TextView showemail;
    private
    DatabaseReference userprofilereference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    //    private String CurrentUserId;
    private
    FirebaseUser user;
    private Button delete;

    @Override
    protected
    void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_account);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance ();
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser ();
        userprofilereference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ().child (user.getUid ());
        showemail = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.edit_emailp);
        showemail.setText (user.getEmail ());
        showprofile = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.profile_name_textView);
        delete = (Button) findViewById (R.id.deleteaccount);


        delete.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public
            void onClick ( View view ) {
                deleteUser ();
                startActivity (new Intent (AccountActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class));

            }
        });
        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid);
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                dataSnapshot.child ("name");
                String name = dataSnapshot.getValue (String.class);
                showprofile.setText (name);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: What would you like to achieve @Aqsa, please add more information to your question

Comment: just attach listener with rootRef  and remove uidRef.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of uid according to your database structure.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        showprofile.setText (name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { 
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

While Ashish's answer will perfectly fine, please note that your current database schema is not a correct one, since you are adding under a `Users` node only a single user. In the future, every time you want to add another user, all the data will be overridden. So the actual solution is to add another layer between the `Users` node and the actual data of the user. Your new database schema might look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- Users
        |
        --- 1P7g ... 57RO (uid)
             |
             --- email: "aqsakarim@gmail.com"
             |
             --- id: "1P7g ... 57RO"
             |
             --- name: "aqsa kari"
             |
             --- uid: "1P7g ... 57RO"
```

In this way, you can distinguish each and every user within your `Users` node. That being said, your actual code will work, as I see you're using that `uid` that comes from the authentication process in your reference. So you don't have to change any line of code, for reading purposes.

**Edit:**

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("Users");
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DocumentReference uidRef = usersRef.document(uid);
uidRef.set(userObject);
```

In which `userObject` is the object that holds all those properties.

Comment: thanks but i dont know how to do it can you help me with this?